# No output while using "gmres" in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a system of linear equalities of the type `Ax = b+u`, where `A` and `b` are known. I used a function in MATLAB like this:

```
x = @(u) gmres(A,b+u);
```

Then I used `fmincon`, where a value for `u` is given to this expression and `x` is computed. For example

```
J = @(u) (x(u)' * x(u) - x^*)^2
```

and

```
[J^*,u] = fmincon(J,...);
```

withe the dots as matrices and vectors for the equalities and inequalities.
My problem is, that MATLAB delivers always an output with information about the command `gmres`. But I have no idea, how I can stop this (it makes the Program much slower).

I hope you know an answer.
Patsch

Comment: Please consider improving you question by adding a [MCVE] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hidden in the documentation, but [it does say](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html#f84-998595)

> No messages are displayed if the `flag` output is specified.

So you need to call `gmres` with at least two outputs.  You can do this by making a wrapper function

```
function x = gmresnomsg(varargin)
    [x,~] = gmres(varargin{:});
end
```

and use that for your handle creation

```
x = @(u) gmresnomsg(A,b+u);
```